# Binding Listbox to a DataTable using Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatable

I'm new to this and Google isn't helping me this time. I was able to follow some examples and populate a DataGrid and modify a database, but ListView is giving me a problem. Here is my class:

```
public class GlobalDataviews : INotifyPropertyChanged   
{
    ...

    //Billable data table
    //Populated elsewhere with "SELECT ID, Value FROM BillableTable;"
    private DataTable mBillable;
    public DataView Billable()
    {
        return mBillable.DefaultView; 
    }  
}
```

Here is my XAML snippets:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="GlobalDataviews" ObjectType="{x:Type local:GlobalDataviews}" />
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="BillableData" ObjectInstance="{StaticResource GlobalDataviews}" MethodName="Billable" />
</Window.Resources>
```

And now for my ListView:

```
<ListBox Name="listBox1" DataContext="{StaticResource BillableData}" SelectedValuePath="ID" DisplayMemberPath="Value"/>
```

I'm probably missing something very simple. What is the correct method? I would also like to bind the selected value (no multiselect) to another property from my code. Can anyone help? Not sure why I'm getting so confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are setting DataContext, you have to set the ItemsSource property to bind data.

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox1" DataContext="{StaticResource BusinessData}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectedValuePath="ID" DisplayMemberPath="Value" />
```

Otherwise, you can bind the ItemsSource directly as follows:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource BusinessData}}" SelectedValuePath="ID" DisplayMemberPath="Value" />
```

Comment: That's what I meant. You have to set ItemsSource in any case. If you have set DataContext, you have to set ItemsSource to just {Binding} so that data binding will happen. Otherwise, you have to assign the source to ItemsSource

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the binding for ItemsSource.

Something like this:

```
<ListBox Name="listBox1" DataContext="{StaticResource BusinessData}" ItemsSource="{Binding myCollection}" SelectedValuePath="ID" DisplayMemberPath="Value"/>
```

Where `myCollection` is a property that exposes your list.

Comment: Are you trying to tell me that I can't populate the list directly from the DataTable? I have to create a collection? If that's the case, why should I specify SelectedValuePath="ID" DisplayMemberPath="Value"?

Comment: @dmaruca: No. You should be able to bind directly to a DataTable, a DataTable is a type of collection. You just need a property to bind to. It's not clear from what you posted what `BusinessData` is supposed to be. If it's actually the table then you should be able to just use `ItemsSource={Binding}` since it's already the data context.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion on BusinessData. I pasted the wrong thing and you replied before I went back and edited it to show the correct names.